# Date formatiing not working , mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to compare `event` filed of my table with current date. I have dates in `event` column in `m/d/Y` format i.e "09/24/2015" .

I am using this query for fetching result which get the records of current date but its returning empty result. I have a record for current date. what is wrong in it ?

`SELECT *
FROM all_tasks
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ) , '%d/%m/%Y' ) = DATE_FORMAT( date( event ) , '%d/%m/%Y' )`

Comment: what is the column type of `event` ?

Comment: You have single quotes around your  table name, so the query won't work.  I vote to close questions with this type of error as a simple typographical error.

Comment: No, I added single quotes so that I can highlight on stackoverflow. skip the quotes and give the answer if you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you store the event as some sort of string, you can just do simply something like:

```
select * from all_tasks where DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m/%d/%Y') = all_tasks.event
```

Here you go a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f1f3/1) sample.